# Cambiar versión PHP Composer Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

He creado un proyecto de Laravel con composer para practicar y, al hacerlo lo he hecho con PHP 7.1 y al desplegar en mi servidor no he podido porque tengo instalado la versión 7.0. ¿Qué solución hay a este problema? He intentado cambiar la versión en el composer.json pero no funciona, da errores.

Al hacer:

```
composer install
```

Me encuentro con este error:

```
- This package requires php >=7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.

- Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
```

Y el composer.json lo podéis ver aquí: https://pastebin.com/4trsDmL0

Comment: ¿qué errores aparecen? por favor muéstranos el contenido de composer.json

Comment: Ya lo he añadido, gracias por la sugerencia ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque al ejecutar el comando *'composer'* por detrás realmente está ejecutando *'php composer.phar...'* y la variable *'php'* almacena la ruta de la versión 7.0 de PHP, por lo que no se ejecuta con la versión requerida.

La solución sería que **instalases la versión 7.1 de PHP de tu servidor**. Si te sigue dando el mismo problema tras hacer lo dicho anteriormente tendrías que modificar la variable de entorno de php con el siguiente comando en la terminal.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php71/bin:$PATH
```

Por supuesto con la ruta correcta de la versión 7.1 de PHP en tu servidor.
Tras hacer esto deberías poder ejecutar los comandos de composer correctamente.

También se pueden usar alias para poder tener distintos perfiles de versiones de PHP para ejecutarse una versión u otra cuando sea necesario. Así se asignan alias:

```
alias php71='/usr/local/php71/bin/php'
```

Espero que te sea una respuesta útil, para mi lo fue en su día.