# Error versión de PHP para instalar Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer

Al ejecutar el comando:

```
composer install
```

Me aparece el siguiente problema:

> Problem 1
>       - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.28) does not satisfy that requirement.

Yo en mi sistema Ubuntu tengo instalado XAMPP, que trae la versión PHP `7.2.4`, pero cuando ejecuto

```
php --version
```

me dice que tengo la `7.0.28`

¿Cómo hago para que el composer me tome la versión del PHP del XAMPP y así poder descargar los vendors de Laravel?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Versiones de PHP diferentes en Servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151930/versiones-de-php-diferentes-en-servidor)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cambiar versión PHP Composer Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137715/cambiar-versi%c3%b3n-php-composer-laravel)

Comment: No me funcionan las soluciones de las otras preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es debido a que composer usa la version `CLI` interfaz de linea de comandos, la cual puede como en tu caso ser diferente a la que usa apache o nginx o el servidor web que uses.

fix rápido:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

eso debería decir que algunas cosas ya estan instaladas y va a instalar otras, luego la versión CLI pasaría a ser la 7.2

si no funciona o quieres cambiar por otras versiones deja un comentario y amplio la respuesta

en caso de que apt no encuentre los paquetes prueba agregando el repositorio PPA

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt update
```

y de nuevo el install

Comment: No encuentra esos paquetes.

Comment: ahi agregue la forma de decirle al apt donde buscarlos

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al usuario de SO en español [cifu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27667/cifu)

Cuya respuesta original esta en este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137715/cambiar-versi%C3%B3n-php-composer-laravel)

Tienes 2 posibles soluciones, la primera

Si te sigue dando el mismo problema tras hacer lo dicho anteriormente tendrías que modificar la variable de entorno de php con el siguiente comando en la terminal.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php71/bin:$PATH
```

Por supuesto con la ruta correcta de la versión 7.2.4 de PHP en tu servidor. Tras hacer esto deberías poder ejecutar los comandos de composer correctamente.

También se pueden usar alias para poder tener distintos perfiles de versiones de PHP para ejecutarse una versión u otra cuando sea necesario. Así se asignan alias:

```
alias php72='/usr/local/php72/bin/php'
```

Comment: No me funcionan las soluciones de las otras preguntas.

Comment: no te entendí que dices?

Comment: Que no me funcionan las soluciones que plantean en las otras preguntas que al parecer son iguales a la mía y ya tienen solución, como la del usuario cifu.