# Instalación de módulos de PHP en distribución Linux Ubuntu v18

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

Buen día, estoy tratando de montar un servidor con la distribución de Linux Ubuntu v18, y poder trabajar con Laravel en PHP7.2, pero al momento de instalar los modulos necesarios con siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip
```

me responde lo siguiente:

```
E: El paquete «php7.2-fpm» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php7.2-mbstring
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php7.2-mbstring»
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php7.2-mbstring»
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php7.2-soap
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php7.2-soap»
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php7.2-soap»
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php7.2-zip
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php7.2-zip»
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php7.2-zip»
```

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal???

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas php7.2 y sea todavía php7.1??? Quizás haya que actualizar los repositorios

Comment: la respuesta  al comando php -v es la siguiente PHP 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

Comment: Y la respuesta a "apt-cache search php7" te da librerías de PHP 7.2???

Comment: "libapache2-mod-php7.2 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language..." si como ve en ese trozo todas las librerías son de php7.2

Comment: necesitarías agregar el repo que trae las ultimas versiones `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` (desde aquí también están disponibles versiones antiguas) ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/157211/81450

Comment: Intentalo con `sudo apt install php-fpm`, Ubuntu 18 ya viene con la versión 7.2 de PHP en su lista de repositorios

Comment: php7 no se encuentran en los repositorios de ubuntu, tienes que compilarlos de forma manual o agregar el repositorio que te dice @aloMalbarez

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip
```

Un saludo