# composer no reconoce mi version de php

Tags: php, xampp, composer

Tengo dos versiones de XAMPP intalados en mi Equipo, (7.1 y 7.3) el problema es que traté de hacer una actualización de una dependencia específica que necesitaba actualizar pero composer me reporta que mi versión de PHP es la 7.1 mientras que la actualización requiere 7.3 pero el servidor XAMPP que tengo activo es el que usa php 7.3 ... esto lo he verificado .. así que por lo viso no es algo relativo al servidor en simismo y el PHP que esté usando de intérprete sino del camino que usa composer para localizar o validar el interprete php. Considerando esto verifiqué desde CMD y en efecto el valor que me devuelve php -v es la versión 7.1

Como sea, el asunto es que no logro hacer que composer actualice las dependencias validando contra la versión PHP 7.3 ... y termina dando error con el argumento que la versión de PHP (7.1) no satisface el requermimiento de la dependencia   :-(

Como puedo cambiar el path o la referencia que tiene composer para validar la versión actualmente activa de PHP?

Argumento que he encontrado otro hilo relativo a este mismo tema al parecer [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137715/cambiar-versi%C3%B3n-php-composer-laravel) pero no me resolvió el problema.

Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno resolví todo actualizando manualmente el valor de path en el sistema.

Propiedades del sistemma > configuración avanzada > variables de entorno > variables del sistema > path

Allí añadí la nueva ruta al interprete php 7.3 y listo .. ya pude actualizar las dependencias en composer.

Saludos!